# Multiple istio control planes in a single cluster

Tags: istio

I have two control plane with different version, so after apply Destination Rule with new LoadBalancing type I got an error below:

istiod logs old version

```
error   watch error in cluster Kubernetes: failed to list *v1alpha3.DestinationRule: v1alpha3.DestinationRuleList.ListMeta: v1.ListMeta.TypeMeta: Kind: Items: []v1alpha3.DestinationRule: v1alpha3.DestinationRule.Spec: unmarshalerDecoder: unknown value "LEAST_REQUEST" for enum istio.networking.v1alpha3.LoadBalancerSettings_SimpleLB, error found in #10 byte of ...|EQUEST"}}}}],"kind":|..., bigger context ...|licy":{"loadBalancer":{"simple":"LEAST_REQUEST"}}}}],"kind":"DestinationRuleList","metadata":{"conti|...
```

Error means that my previous istio version, does not know about this type LoadBalancing and istiod failed with error.
How to split my new version istio from old version?

How to do compatibility with earlier versions or split visibility for control plane?

Comment: Have you used revision tags? (https://istio.io/v1.16/blog/2021/revision-tags/)

Comment: @peterj Sure, but it didn't help